# Hide BottomNavigationMenu in a scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, bottomnavigationview

I need to create a bottomnavigationmenu that hides like in that one link:
https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/ahbottomnavigation

But instead of make it fade by scroll, fade with timer, like, 2 seconds of inactivity

Any hints? I don't know how to access the behavior of the scroll through my main activity

Comment: fade with timer for this you need to create your own custom bottom bar with Handler and hide bottom bar on scroll, plus you need to take care of many things to achieve "2 seconds of inactivity".

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I tried to use disconnectCallback and Runnable, but it's not working inside a fragment, so I made something else, and it's kinda ok